# Parsing Datetime in Python with timezone

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, datetime, timezone, utc

How do I parse this date and time with the time zone?

```
date_time=datetime.strptime("2017-06-04T01:00:00+04:00", '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z')
```

I am getting error like

`ValueError: time data '2017-06-04T01:00:00+04:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S %Z`'

while I remove "%Z" the error is like

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains: +04:00
```

I think the error is in formatting time zone. Please help on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse using `dateutil package`

```
import dateutil.parser

dateutil.parser.parse('2008-09-03T20:56:35.450686Z')

datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 4, 1, 0, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 14400))
```

for install package

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

Answer (score 1):

Use lowercase z for this form of timezone

```
date_time=datetime.strptime("2017-06-04T01:00:00+04:00", '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear to me that `strptime` has a directive for coping with time zone information in that format. The part of the string in indicating time zone needs to be without the colon.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime("2017-06-04T01:00:00+0400", '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 4, 1, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0, 14400)))
```

You can arrange to preprocess the date with a regex of course:

```
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=[+=][0-9]{2}):', '', "2017-06-04T01:00:00+04:00")
'2017-06-04T01:00:00+0400'
```

If you can allow yourself the use of a library that is not part of the standard distribution then arrow would be suitable for this since it's especially good with timestamps.

```
>>> import arrow
>>> arrow.get("2017-06-04T01:00:00+04:00")
<Arrow [2017-06-04T01:00:00+04:00]>
```